Is it possible to create an API connection to QuickBooks desktop using Google Apps Script?
I have seen articles that demonstrate how to connect to QuickBooks Online's API using Apps Script. I was just wondering if it's possible to do the same with QuickBooks Desktop. My use case for example is to be able to extract the invoice data via API. Has anyone tried this before? I'd greatly appreciate any help on this.
I have only seen articles referring to QuickBooks Online but not with QB Desktop.

I believe setting up an API connection with QB Desktop requires you to setup and host your own server. If you are technically inclined try reading Quickbook's official reference documentation.

From Get started with QuickBooks web connector

Get started with QuickBooks web connector
The QuickBooks Web Connector (QBWC) is a Microsoft Windows application that enables web services (web-based applications) to exchange data with QuickBooks Desktop products (including QuickBooks Financial Software and QuickBooks Point of Sale). Your web service is deployed in a web server, which may be hosted locally or by a hosting service. Web Connector is installed on the same machine as QuickBooks (or at least on the same local network).

Also, you might have to install the Quickbooks Desktop SDK. For details, see Download and install the SDK.
Related

QuickBooks Desktop Sync with Zoho CRM, Bidirectionally

